# Create custom user based authentication for use with Blazor Server vs Identity authentication

Tags: authentication, .net-core, asp.net-identity, blazor

I should preface this by saying that I am very new to .Net and web development in general - there's likely a very easy solution to this and I apologize in advance for all the rambling contained in this post.

Essentially what I am trying to do is require that users log in to an account that is created for them by a site administrator - simply an email and password. From there, I want these users to be able to go through a few steps to populate a SQL database with some information, and link the information in the database to the user to allow for future access(my plan is to do this using a relational DB)

I tried to implement this through the identity authentication that Blazor has available out of the box however I ran into a couple of issues:

My first issue was being unable to redirect users to the login page that Identity provides - Ideally this login page would be a Blazor component instead of a razor page so the page would have a uniform layout to it, however, this did not work for me - and redirecting to the login page caused an awkward flash of the home page of the site, before redirecting to the login page.

My second issue was in attempting to use the Identity user-id as a parameter for the route manager, as it provided me with some errors, as well as a very long string that led me to believe the Id might be encrypted? (I'm over my head with understanding what's happening in this authentication system)

All this leads me to think that it would be simpler to create my own authentication that works with the Blazor component UI a little better(although I could definitely be way off with this), as it's an application for internal use & I really don't need a lot of the things that are provided with Identity authentication (two-factor, lockouts, all those other things). However, I am not sure where to start with this, as simply creating a DB table feels as though it would be insecure, and I do need the authorization functionality for server admins to create new user accounts and such.

I guess after all that the question is, should I continue trying to work with the Identity authentication to get it to cooperate with what I'm doing, or should I attempt to create my own form of authentication?

Comment: Two years later, I find myself asking the same question. I went down the path of using AspNetCore.Identity, but the further along I get, the less it seems like it's helping or saving me any time. I am also struggling with the same issue of the identity pages not matching the look and feel of the rest of my Blazor app, and it seems like it's a hack to change that. I'm feeling completely confused by all of it now and thinking I'd be better off implementing my own user management, authentication and authorization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to say learn to use the Identity Server. Rolling your own authentication is something you should leave to experts or your data will be the next set available on the dark web.

The long string you are talking about I suspect is the Id of the user. It is a GUID or UUID depending on your schooling.

I am not sure you understand your solution has two UI's.
The Server is managing all the identity management screens and they can be overwritten but these are not your Blazor app, switching between them would be "awkward flash" you mention.

You can customize these screens for additional properties there are plenty of posts about that. You could create DTO's for partial updates via an API which would keep the user experience within the app more.